# How to authenticate on ionic with firebase using rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ionic4

I'm creating a authentication page on ionic 4 and I need to integrate the google auth to make the process easier.

But I don't want to store the users on firebase, because I have a backend on ruby on rails 5 application.

How to integrate google auth with rails api?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the backend builded in rails you will need to validated the google auth first in the ionic app as explained in here. https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-google-login#authentication-options you have 3 options, your is **The handcrafted way (using your own API/Backend)**.

After get the authorization token from google you have to send it through your api and validates the token. To validate the token use the gem `google-id-token` and the your controller should looks like this

```
token = params[:token]
validator = GoogleIDToken::Validator.new(expiry: 1800)
begin
    payload = validator.check(token, client_id)
    user_id = payload['sub']
    email = payload['email']
    picture = payload['picture']
    name = payload['name']
    head :ok
rescue GoogleIDToken::ValidationError => e
    head 404
end
```

For more information about this gem https://github.com/google/google-id-token

Also for the client_id it should be generated when you create an app in google console.